# Can I call DjangoREST APIs from a Laravel application

Tags: python, django, laravel

I have worked on a React-Native application that uses DjangoREST apis to use the database. Basically the backend is on Django.

Now I have designed a Laravel web-app for the same organization. Can I call those same APIs so that I can use the same database

Comment: Err... An HTTP request is an HTTP request, whatever language / techno / framework the client is coded in.

Comment: If you want to call that API from the controller the User Guzzle HTTP laravel have default Http library or you need to this data on blade file the use simple ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You don't have to care about stack of API when calling HTTP API. I recommend you have a deeper understanding of Web communications.

- [Web API Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API)
- [HTTP Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)